# Does portability come to the cost of unchanging variable sizes in C#?

Tags: c#

Is this true? For performance-intensive applications using C# on 64-bit systems, I found this surprising in my book:

> C# strictly specifies a range and behavior for each value type.
>   Because of portability requirements, C# is uncompromising on this
>   account. For example, an int is the same in all execution
>   environments. There is no need to rewrite code to fit a specific
>   platform. Although strictly specifying the size of the value types may
>   cause a small loss of performance in some environments, it is
>   necessary in order to achieve portability.

Comment: Until this day I have never seen anything to confirm this, but everything I've ever read or experienced regarding C#, VB, and lately F#, indicates that that's the way it is, and I can't see how it could be otherwise.

Comment: Understandable, though it doesn't seem beneficial for performance-sensitive applications that target specific platforms (i.e. padding, etc.). Then again, I guess C++ would be a better route to go if performance requirements is a reasonable concern.

Comment: In practice this "cost" is zero because all 64-bit processors can perform 32-bit operations just as efficiently as 64-bit operations.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the language, but on the compiler and runtime environment. I believe there are plans for an F# compiler for .NET Native that will use the same compiler backend (and optimizations) as C++, which kind of illustrates the point.

Comment: In game development I learned about structure padding so it's moving along a dword boundry, etc. If an int stays 32-bit on a 64-bit platform, I guess moving ints to longs are necessary, 32-bit padding, etc. As you can tell, I came from a C++ background, but recently enjoying C# again for potential development. Sounds like C# asks the developer not to worry about these little details, and let the compiler and CLR deal with it--still scary for some devs.

Comment: Is what true? That C# strictly specifies sizes of types? (Or rather, .NET does). That doing so _"**may** cause a small loss of performance in **some** environments"_? What is it that you actually need help with here? There doesn't seem to be a real question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portability is 'more' *guaranteed* by the unchanging variable sizes in C# (or really, the .NET/CLR/ECMA-355 specifications, of which C# is just one language).

This is just one of many guarantees that ensure that *code* (and the resulting MSIL) are portable across compilation and run-time systems. On the other hand, making assumptions about the size of `int` in C is rather *unportable*.

The "cost" is only in certain implementations that must still provide the guarantee to correctly execute the resulting MSIL - and one requirement is a 64-bit `long` value. Not all systems have an associated "cost" and on an AMD64 system there is effectively zero "extra work" to do. Also, C# is not a 'bare metal' language.. and is not always the [most] appropriate language to use.

Comment: I understand now on a C# perspective, though it's not beneficial for game developers, graphics-intense, etc. On a side note, C doesn't specify the size of a value type, just its minimal size.

Comment: @Phil There are *many* games written in C#. There are also *many* games written in Java (well, 'Android Java'). C# is not the ideal choice for *every* game or every platform: the requirements and resources need to be defined first. Then again, neither is C/C++. I think, in general, the *bigger* issues with C# game development is Garbage Collection. C/C++ force manual deallocations which amortize the cost and avoid 'hiccups'; also, thinking at the lower levels may help design in ways to reduce churn.

Comment: True, garbage collection is an issue, too. I guess everything just depends on the project.

Comment: There is a lot of effort going into improvements with GC on .NET platforms these days, including on Mono.

Comment: @BentTranberg I'm a fan of C#/.NET for most all general productivity and backend development .. I wouldn't use it to write The Next Awesome FPS :D

Comment: Yeah, C# for GUI, C++ for games is becoming my growing philosophy. .Net Native looks interesting to look into though. Anyway, thanks for verifying this interesting topic.

Comment: I kind of did that in my former position, and it was called ... Next. A video surveillance system that displayed lots of real time video and did real time video analysis at the same time. Mix of C++, C# and F#. The C++ was fast, but no longer essential as technology progressed.

Comment: Itis beneficial for any development. Imainge you program and then compile on another platform and your game crashes because your "int" went suddenly from 32 to 16 bit. Actually not having defined behavior (and size = value space = part of behavior) is one of the mistakes in classic C. You program assuming a variable can hold a specific range of values - how that is implemented is less important than that this value space is not "randomly" smaller.by compiling on another machine. Performance may suffer - but at least the program can run.

Comment: I'm sure that's fine for 99% of C# game developers. Pretty good chance they're not making the next Elder Scrolls game.